# Invalid name when running do file

Tags: graph, histogram, stata

I am getting "Invalid name" when running the following code

```
foreach i in 2008 2009 2010 2011{
disp `"Working in Year `i'"'
tostring `i', local(yearStr)
disp `"yearStr"'
graph bar E if Year=="'i'", c(1) name ('i',replace)
histogram E if Year=="`i'", c(1) name (`yearStr',replace)
}
```

What I am trying to do is plot a graph bar between years and "E" by choosing the years 2008 2009 2010 2011 from a dataset that I have already input. But whenever I try to run the code, the same error is found.

Error :

```
    Working on year 2008
2008 invalid name
r(198);
```

Comment: -1 for lack of research. Some of your syntax is fantasy syntax. You need to study the documentation much more carefully while coding.

Comment: Don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors and misconceptions here.

Your code fails on `tostring 2008` as `tostring` expects variable name(s). Nor does `tostring` support a `local()` option, but Stata doesn't get that far. However, string conversion is not needed here at all. A macro *is* a string.

Your code can be rewritten as

```
forval i = 2008/2011 {
    graph bar E if Year == "`i'", subtitle(`i') name(B`i', replace)
    histogram E if Year == "`i'", subtitle(`i') name(H`i',replace)
}
```

Some of the details that arise:

1. Warning. For this to work, `Year` must be a string variable, which doesn't sound useful elsewhere. `Year` would be better as numeric.
2. Syntax. I corrected the macro punctuation to different left and right quotes.
3. Syntax. I cut out the option `c(1)`. What do you expect that to do? I know of no such relevant option. Perhaps you want to connect with a line, which would be `c(l)`, except that would not work with either of these commands.
4. Style. The intent of your code seems to be take the contents of macro `i` and put it in another macro `yearStr`. There is no need to do that.
5. Syntax. `name()` is better presented without a space, and pure numbers cannot be legal graph names.
6. Intent. As in your code the macros `i` and `yearStr` would have identical contents you are by accident trying (e.g.) to create a graph with name `2008` and then overwrite it, as the next graph would have the same name. As above, the syntax is illegal any way, but only different names make any kind of sense.
7. Graph style. Better to put the year as text on each graph to explain which each shows.
8. Intent. The line `di "yearStr"` would just display the literal `yearStr`. It wouldn't display a local macro with that name. (I simplified out the compound double quotes.)

All that said, with four years, you will probably be better off with

```
graph bar E, by(Year) 
histogram E, by(Year)
```

However, if there is just one value of `E` for each year, you may want something more like

```
twoway bar E year, base(0)
```